# Database update row how to - Android

Tags: android, database

If you look at my code at the bottom, I have database with column 'used'. If it's 1 it means that it haven't been used, when it is used it set to update the number to 0. But when all of the rows have used number 0, then I would like to update used from 0 to 1 again in all of the rows.

I think of using this:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=1 WHERE kategorija=" + kategorija4 + ";");
```

But where in my code should I put it? Should I add something? Is it the right code to use?

```
public void set(){
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    String vprasanje = "";

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("baza.db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor cd=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM vprasanja WHERE kategorija=" + kategorija4 + " AND used = 1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);
    cd.moveToFirst();

    if(cd.moveToFirst()){

    vprasanje = cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("text"));

    //patch
    String id2 = (cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("id")));
    int idd2 = Integer.parseInt(id2);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=0 WHERE id =" + idd2 + ";");


    beseda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    beseda.setText("");
    beseda.setText(vprasanje);


    db.close();
    busy = 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(cd.moveToFirst()){
```

You should use

```
if(cd.getCount() != 0){
```

Then add an else

```
//all values are used
else {
   db.execSQL("UPDATE vprasanja SET used=1 WHERE kategorija=" + kategorija4 + ";");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, I think it will help you:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put("used", 0);
db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "id" + "='" + idd2 + "'", null) > 0;
```